# Finding a list of divs with a specific class in Watir

Tags: watir

We have n-number of divs on the page with the same class name.

```
<div class="errors">
</div>
<div class="errors">
            Foo is invalid
</div>
```

What we'd like to do is to check and see if any of the divs with the "error" class on them have the message "Foo is invalid".

We can do this
                @browser.div(:class => 'errors', :index => 2)

But that doesn't cover the case where the message is in the first or n-th div.

What would be great is if we can get all the matching divs back as an array, flatten it out, and then do our assertions.

Or perhaps get back the number of divs that match so that we can iterate over them.

We are on Watir 1.9.2

Answer (score 5):

If you upgrade to Watir 2.0 or if you use watir-webdriver gem, this would return all divs that have class `errors` and text (exactly) `Foo is invalid` (if that is what you want to do):

```
browser.divs(:class => "errors", :text => "Foo is invalid")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get bogged down with a complex solution.  Start with general (even inefficient) steps first and then streamline the code once the basic solution is working.  This will work in Watir 1.9.2:

```
@divs_with_error = []  #create a new array for the divs with class == "error"
@divs_invalid = []     #create a new array for the divs with text == "Foo is invalid"

browser.divs.each do |div|      #for each div on the page
  if div.class == "error"       #if the class == "error"
     @divs_with_error << div    #add it to our array
  end
end

@divs_with_error.each do |div|     #for each div in the @divs_with_error array
  if div.text == "Foo is invalid"  #if the text == "Foo is invalid"
    @divs_invalid << div           #add it to our next array
  end
end
```

If this collects the data you are looking for, you can simplify it into a single block:

```
@divs_with_error = []   #create a new array

browser.divs.each do |div|
  if ((div.text == "Foo is invalid") && (div.class == "error"))
     @divs_with_error << div
  end
end
```

You may need to use div.text.include? if there is other text in the failing div elements.  You can also use the collect! method with the arrays to save some more space.  As always, rather than collecting the entire div element, you can collect certain attributes only:

```
@divs_with_error << [div.text, div.index]
@divs_with_error << div.class
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I mentioned it, I just didn't provide the example :D.